# How to adjust static control to display Arabic (Right-to-left) text?

Tags: c++, user-interface, winapi, dialog, internationalization

*I want to say right off the bat that I don't speak any of the Arabic languages.*

I am trying to internationalize my dialog window by translating its simple text (using Google Translate service.)

The message is displayed using two `static` text controls. In default configuration, they have the following styles:

```
//Top window:
//Wnd Styles: 0x50020001 = WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_GROUP | SS_CENTER
//Wnd ExStyles: 0x4 = WS_EX_NOPARENTNOTIFY

//Bottom window:
//Wnd Styles: 0x50020000 = WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_GROUP | SS_LEFT
//Wnd ExStyles: 0x4 = WS_EX_NOPARENTNOTIFY
```

This is how I display English text:

```
pStrPleaseRead = L"*** PLEASE READ ***";
pStrMsg = L"Check your \"Spam\" or \"Other\" folders if you don't see that email right away.";

this->SetDlgItemText(IDC_STATIC_PLS_READ, pStrPleaseRead);
this->SetDlgItemText(IDC_STATIC_MSG, pStrMsg);
```

which makes it look as such:

[image]

So then when translating it to any of the right-to-left languages, I first make two translations. Here's one:

[image]

and then this one:

[image]

I then copy both results into Visual Studio as strings, and adjust my code as such:

[image]

```
pStrPleaseRead = L"*** בבקשה תקרא ***";
pStrMsg = L"בדוק את התיקיות 'ספאם' או 'אחר' אם אינך רואה את האימייל מיד.";

//Need to apply R-T-L reading

static UINT ctrlIDs[] = {
    IDC_STATIC_PLS_READ,
    IDC_STATIC_MSG,
};

for(int i = 0; i < _countof(ctrlIDs); i++)
{
    CWnd* pW = this->GetDlgItem(ctrlIDs[i]);
    ASSERT(pW);
    pW->ModifyStyleEx(0, WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL | WS_EX_RTLREADING | WS_EX_RIGHT);
}

this->SetDlgItemText(IDC_STATIC_PLS_READ, pStrPleaseRead);
this->SetDlgItemText(IDC_STATIC_MSG, pStrMsg);
```

But this is how it comes out. The first translation (in red) is correct, but the second one (below it) is not:

[image]

(This is how the Google version looks like):

[image]

Again, I can't read it. I'm just comparing it to how it looked originally in Google Translate window.

So what am I missing there?

PS. For this project I'm stuck with Visual Studio 2008 IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Arabic reading order is from right to left, so Google Translate will also translate in Arabic reading order.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left

Such as:
   [image: ep]
   [image: ep2]

> So you'll find that when you output to a static text box, the text is in the right-to-left row.

Comment: BTW this is hebrew not arabic, but the reasoning is the same as both languages are RTL

Comment: @Jabberwocky: OK, sorry. You're right. But still, it doesn't answer my question. Why is it displayed differently in the `static` control vs. what I see in Google Translate?

Comment: @c00000fd Because Google translates Hebrew from right to left in turn, and we normally read it from left to right. Carefully, you will find that the **'. '** of Hebrew you translated above is on the left of the second line.